# Spin covariant derivative of gamma matrices?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

Where can I find a general expression (on curved manifolds) in local coordinates, for the following: $$\nabla^S_{\mu}\gamma^{\nu} = ?$$
$\nabla^S_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} + \omega^S_{\mu}$ is the spin covariant derivative associated to the spin connection $\omega^S_{\mu}$ and the gamma matrices satisfy: $$\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\} = 2g^{\mu\nu}.$$

Comment: I suppose $\nu$ is a space time (coordinate) index? Please define what $\gamma^{\nu}$ is then. The usual definition of gamma matrices have an internal Lorentz index, but it is also just convenient (and confusing) notation. Gamma matrices are just pre-defined constants, they transform trivially under diffeos and local Lorentz. The reason we write an uppercase Lorentz index is that $\bar{\psi} \gamma^I \psi$ actually transforms like a Lorentz vector, but not because of gamma matrices: it is $\psi$ that’s transformation law is responsible for this.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus they would be constants in the flat case, hence there is no question of their derivatives there. However, in the case of curved manifold, I'm not sure why that should be the case.

Comment: I am telling you that it is still the case in the curved spacetime. The coordinate-dependent version is related to constant matrices by $\gamma^{\mu} = e^{\mu}_I \gamma^I$ where $e$ is the tetrad field.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Yes, indeed, that's right. Then, the derivative would basically entail the derivative of the tetrad field, i.e. $\nabla^S_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu} = (\nabla^S_{\mu}e^{\mu}_I)\gamma^I$?

Comment: Exactly. And the compatibility condition says that the tetras is covariantly constant, so your derivative is still zero.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus oh wait, but what about the second term in $\nabla^S_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu} = (\nabla^S_{\mu}e^{\mu}_I)\gamma^I + e^{\mu}_I \nabla^S_{\mu}\gamma^{I}$, how is that necessarily zero? I guess, it gives $e^{\mu}_I\omega^S_{\mu}\gamma^I$.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by covariant differentiation, but if spin connection acts on internal indices then yes you’re right.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I edited it in the question.

Comment: Also shared this reference in another question of yours, but Equation C.5 in Appendix C of https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0405033 may be what you want. There are references to other approaches as well.